# How does std::set comparator function work?

Tags: c++, set

Currently working on an algorithm problems using set.

```
set<string> mySet;
mySet.insert("(())()");
mySet.insert("()()()");

//print mySet: 
(())()
()()()
```

Ok great, as expected.

However if I put a comp function that sorts the set by its length, I only get 1 result back.

```
struct size_comp
{
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) const{
        return a.size()>b.size();
    }
};
set<string, size_comp> mySet;
mySet.insert("(())()");
mySet.insert("()()()");

//print myset
(())()
```

Can someone explain to me why?

I tried using a multi set, but its appending duplicates.

```
multiset<string,size_comp> mSet;
mSet.insert("(())()");
mSet.insert("()()()");
mSet.insert("()()()");
//print mset
"(())()","()()()","()()()"
```

Comment: Consider use of `std::multiset`, which would allow you to have both strings in the set, even if they compare equal (by length).

Comment: If you also have to lexicographically compare the strings with same length, the comparator should return: `a.size() < b.size() || (a.size() == b.size() && a < b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator template argument, which defaults to `std::less<T>`, must represent a *strict weak ordering* relation between values in its domain.

This kind of relation has some requirements:

- it's not reflexive (`x < x` yields false)
- it's asymmetric (`x < y` implies that `y < x` is false)
- it's transitive (`x < y && y < z` implies `x < z`)

Taking this further we can define equivalence between values in term of this relation, because if `!(x < y) && !(y < x)` then it must hold that `x == y`.

In your situation you have that `∀ x, y` such that `x.size() == y.size()`, then both `comp(x,y) == false && comp(y,x) == false`, so since no `x` or `y` is lesser than the other, then they must be equal.

This equivalence is used to determine if two items correspond to the same, thus ignoring second insertion in your example.

To fix this you must make sure that your comparator never returns false for both `comp(x,y)` and `comp(y,x)` if you don't want to consider `x` equal to `y`, for example by doing

```
auto cmp = [](const string& a, const string& b) {
  if (a.size() != b.size())
    return a.size() > b.size();
  else
    return std::less()(a, b);
}
```

So that for input of same length you fallback to normal lexicographic order.

Comment: Why return `std::less()(a, b)` instead of `a < b`?

Comment: @user2079303: personal preference, both `std::less` overload for strings and `string::operator<` resolve to the same lexicographic comparison.

Comment: The second one is antisymmetry, not asymmetry.

Comment: @M.M: actually asymmetry implies antisymmetry, and antisymmetry and irreflexivity imply asymmetry. So in in the end it's the same, it's just redundant. Actually irreflexivity and transitivity imply asymmetry so there's no need to include it at all :)

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` stores unique values only. Two values `a,b` are considered equivalent **if and only if**

```
!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)
```

or in everyday language, if `a` is not smaller than `b` and `b` is not smaller than `a`. In particular, *only* this criterion is used to check for equality, the normal `operator==` is not considered at all.

So with your comparator, the set can only contain one string of length `n` for every `n`.

If you want to allow multiple values that are equivalent under your comparison, use [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multisethttp://). This will of course also allow exact duplicates, again, under your comparator, `"asdf"` is just as equivalent to `"aaaa"` as it is to `"asdf"`.

If that does not make sense for your problem, you need to come up with either a different comparator that induces a proper notion of equality or use another data structure.

---

A quick fix to get the behavior you probably want (correct me if I'm wrong) would be introducing a secondary comparison criterion like the normal `operator>`. That way, we sort by length first, but are still able to distinguish between different strings of the same length.

```
struct size_comp
{
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) const{
        if (a.size() != b.size())
            return a.size() > b.size();
        return a > b;
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried using a multi set, but its appending duplicates. "(())()","()()()","()()()"

Comment: @WeiZeng Of course, that's the purpose of `multiset`. Just keep in mind that your comparator is the *only* criterion for equality that is used, I tried to clarify that in my answer.

Comment: What do I add to my comparator function so that it doesnt append dups? I tried `return a.size()>b.size() && a!=b;`

Comment: @WeiZeng So how did that turn out? :) If that did not work it may be worth asking a new question for that, including a proper MCVE.

Comment: I stuck with `std::set` using a better comparator function. Thank you for your explainations.

Answer (score 1):

This is because equality of elements is defined by the comparator. An element is considered equal to another if and only if `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

Since the length of `"(())()"` is not greater, nor lesser than the length of `"()()()"`, they are considered equal by your comparator. There can be only unique elements in a `std::set`, and an equivalent object will overwrite the existing one.

The default comparator uses `operator<`, which in the case of strings, performs lexicographical ordering.

> I tried using a multi set, but its appending duplicates.

Multiset indeed does allow duplicates. Therefore both strings will be contained despite having the same length.

Answer (score 0):

size_comp considers only the length of the strings. The default comparison operator uses lexicographic comparison, which distinguishes based on the content of the string as well as the length.